# Install x-pack java.net.UnknownHostException: artifacts.elastic.co

Tags: java

Environment：

- centos7
- elasticsearch：5.2.2
- kibana 5.2.2

In elasticsearch, when I installed x-pack, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: artifacts.elastic.co
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadZip(InstallPluginCommand.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadZipAndChecksum(InstallPluginCommand.java:322)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.download(InstallPluginCommand.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:210)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:47)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: artifacts.elastic.co
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2982)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:398)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadZip(InstallPluginCommand.java:278)
        ... 10 more
```

I tried the following solution, but did not succeed:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

I added

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I am stuck at this point. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

At this time because my virtual machine can not connect to the external network caused（这时因为我的虚拟机不能连接外网造成的）

In the windows network connection - local connection - share --- Integer connection sharing check removed（在windows中网络连接  -- 本地连接 -- 共享 --- Integer连接共享 勾选去掉）

Answer (score 0):

Try to use exporting a system variable `ES_JAVA_OPTS` with http and https settings. In ubuntu you can do something like this:
`export ES_JAVA_OPTS="$ES_JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=port -Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=post"`

Hope it was helpful as it solved the same problem with elasticsearch of version 6.0.0